# Bad or long request

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a long form to fit and sometimes the session is invalid and when I press the submit button I lose all of my data. Luckily, I managed to save the next url after the redirect on login form. It works fine without any problems with other links.

But When I Try the query bellow of the long form :

```
 http://localhost:8080/ao-server/administration/connexion_admin?next=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fao-server%2Fadministration%2FAO%2Fsave%3Fetat_ao%3Dnew%26pme%3D0%26acheteur%3D1274%26typemarche%3D9%26reference%3D51%252FMEK%252F2016%2B%26dateouvertureplis%3D01%252F12%252F2016%26heure%3D09%26minute%3D00%26objet%3DEtude%2BArchitecturale%2Bet%2Bsuivi%2Bdes%2Btravaux%2Bd%25E2%2580%2599extension%2Bde%2BS%252FS%2BOuled%2BSlime%2Bcentre%2BCR%2BM%25E2%2580%2599Haya%2BProvince%2Bde%2BMekn%25C3%25A8s%2B%26estimation%3D2%26provinces%3D17-3%26datepublication%3D05%252F11%252F2016%26selectedactivites%3D505-3%26idao%3D16399%26from%3Dcontrole%26idfils%3D%26idModif%3D%26origin%3D%26content%3D%253Cstrong%253EROYAUME%2BDU%2BMAROC%2B%253Cbr%253E%253Cbr%253EMINIST%25C3%2588RE%2BDE%2BL%25E2%2580%2599EDUCATION%2BNATIONALE%2BET%2BDE%2BLA%2BFORMATION%2BPROFESSIONNELLE%2B%253Cbr%253E%253Cbr%253EACAD%25C3%2589MIE%2BR%25C3%2589GIONALE%2BDE%2BL%25E2%2580%2599%25C3%2589DUCATION%2BET%2BDE%2BLA%2BFORMATION%2BR%25C3%2589GION%2BDE%2BF%25C3%2588S-MEKN%25C3%2588S%2B%253Cbr%253E%253Cbr%253EDIRECTION%2BPROVINCIALE%2BDE%2BMEKN%25C3%2588S%2B%253Cbr%253E%253Cbr%253ESERVICE%2BDES%2BAFFAIRES%2BADMINISTRATIVES%2BET%2BFINANCI%25C3%2588RES%2B%253Cbr%253E%253Cbr%253EBUREAU%2BDES%2BMARCHES%253C%252Fstrong%253E%253Cbr%253E%253Cbr%253E%253Cbr%253EAVIS%2BDE%2BCONSULTATION%2BARCHITECTURALE%2BN%25C2%25B0%25C2%25A0%253Cstrong%253E51%252FMEK%252F2016%253C%252Fstrong%253E%25C2%25A0%253Cbr%253E%253Cbr%253E%253Cbr%253E%253Cstrong%253ELe%2B01%252F12%252F2016%2B%25C3%25A0%2Bpartir%2Bde%2B09%2BH%253C%252Fstrong%253E%2B%252Cselon%2Bci-apr%25C3%25A8s%252C%2Bil%2Bsera%2Bproc%25C3%25A9d%25C3%25A9%2Bdans%2Bla%2Bsalle%2Bdes%2Br%25C3%25A9unions%2B%25C3%25A0%2Bla%2BDirection%2BProvinciale%2Bde%2BAcad%25C3%25A9mie%2Br%25C3%25A9gionale%2Bde%2Bl%25E2%2580%2599%25C3%25A9ducation%2Bet%2Bde%2Bla%2Bformation%2BR%25C3%25A9gion%2Bde%2BF%25C3%25A8s-Mekn%25C3%25A8s%252C%2BAvenue%2BAbdelkrim%2BEl%2BKhattabi%2BSbata%2B%25C3%25A0%2BMekn%25C3%25A8s%2B%25C3%25A0%2Bl%25E2%2580%2599ouverture%2Bdes%2Bplis%2Bdes%2Barchitectes%2Brelatif%2Bau%2Bconsultation%2Barchitecturale%2Bsuivante%253A%2B%253Cbr%253E%253Cbr%253E-%2BN%25C2%25B0%2Bde%2Bla%2Bconsultation%2Barchitecturale%253A%2B%253Cstrong%253E51%252FMEK%252F2016%253C%252Fstrong%253E%2B%253Cbr%253E%253Cbr%253E-%2BObjet%253A%2B%253Cstrong%253EEtude%2BArchitecturale%2Bet%2Bsuivi%2Bdes%2Btravaux%2Bd%25E2%2580%2599extension%2Bde%2BS%252FS%2BOuled%2BSlime%2Bcentre%2BCR%2BM%25E2%2580%2599Haya%2BProvince%2Bde%2BMekn%25C3%25A8s%253C%252Fstrong%253E%2B%253Cbr%253E%253Cbr%253E%253Cstrong%253E-%2BBudget%2BPr%25C3%25A9visionnel%2Bmax%2BHT%253C%252Fstrong%253E%2Bpour%2Bl%25E2%2580%2599ex%25C3%25A9cution%2Bdes%2Btravaux%2Ben%2BDhs%253A%2B%253Cstrong%253E666%2B000.00%2BDH%253C%252Fstrong%253E%2BSix%2Bcent%2Bsoixante-six%2Bmille%2B%253Cbr%253E%253Cbr%253ELe%2Bdossier%2Bde%2Bla%2Bconsultation%2Barchitecturale%2Bpeut%2B%25C3%25AAtre%2Bretir%25C3%25A9%2Bau%2BBureau%2Bdes%2Bmarch%25C3%25A9s%2Bde%2Bla%2BDirection%2BProvinciale%2Bde%2Bl%25E2%2580%2599AREF%2BR%25C3%25A9gion%2BF%25C3%25A8s-Mekn%25C3%25A8s%2B%25C3%25A0%2BMekn%25C3%25A8s%252C%2Bil%2Bpeut%2B%25C3%25A9galement%2B%25C3%25AAtre%2Bt%25C3%25A9l%25C3%25A9charg%25C3%25A9%2B%25C3%25A0%2Bpartir%2Bdu%2Bportail%2Bdes%2Bmarch%25C3%25A9s%2Bpublics%2Bwww.marchespublics.gov.ma%2B%253Cbr%253E%253Cbr%253ELe%2Bcontenu%2Bainsi%2Bque%2Bla%2Bpr%25C3%25A9sentation%2Bdes%2Bdossiers%2Bdes%2Bconcurrents%2Bdoivent%2B%25C3%25AAtre%2Bconformes%2Baux%2Bdispositions%2Bdes%2Barticles%2B100%252C%2B101%2Bet%2B102%2Bdu%2Bd%25C3%25A9cret%2Bn%25C2%25B0%2B2-12-349%2Bdu%2B8%2Bjoumada%2BI%2B1434%2B%252820%2Bmars%2B2013%2529%2Bfixant%2Bles%2Bconditions%2Bet%2Bles%2Bformes%2Bde%2Bpassation%2Bdes%2Bmarch%25C3%25A9s%2Bpour%2Ble%2Bcompte%2Bde%2Bl%25E2%2580%2599Etat%2Bet%2Bdes%2B%25C3%25A9tablissements%2Bpublics%2Bainsi%2Bque%2Bcertaines%2Br%25C3%25A8gles%2Brelatives%2B%25C3%25A0%2Bleurs%2Bgestion%2Bet%2B%25C3%25A0%2Bleur%2Bcontr%25C3%25B4le.%2B%253Cbr%253E%253Cbr%253ELes%2Barchitectes%2Bpeuvent%253A%2B%253Cbr%253E%253Cbr%253E-Soit%2Bd%25C3%25A9poser%2Bcontre%2Br%25C3%25A9c%25C3%25A9piss%25C3%25A9%2Bleurs%2Bplis%2Bdans%2BBureau%2Bdes%2Bmarch%25C3%25A9s%2Bde%2Bla%2BDirection%2BProvinciale%2Bde%2BMekn%25C3%25A8s.%2B%253Cbr%253E-Soit%2Bles%2Benvoyer%252C%2Bpar%2Bcourrier%2Brecommand%25C3%25A9%2Bavec%2Baccus%25C3%25A9%2Bde%2Br%25C3%25A9ception%2Bau%2BBureau%2Bpr%25C3%25A9cit%25C3%25A9.%2B%253Cbr%253E-Soit%2Bles%2Bremettre%2Bau%2Bpr%25C3%25A9sident%2Bdu%2Bjury%2Bde%2Bla%2Bconsultation%2Barchitecturale%2Bau%2Bd%25C3%25A9but%2Bde%2Bla%2Bs%25C3%25A9ance%2Bet%2Bavant%2Bl%25E2%2580%2599ouverture%2Bdes%2Bplis.%2B%253Cbr%253E%253Cbr%253ELes%2Bpi%25C3%25A8ces%2Bjustificatives%2B%25C3%25A0%2Bfournir%2Bsont%2Bcelles%2Bpr%25C3%25A9vues%2Bpar%2Bl%25E2%2580%2599article%2B10%2Bdu%2Br%25C3%25A8glement%2Bde%2Bconsultation%2Barchitecturale.%253Cbr%253E%253Cbr%253E%2BLes%2Bpi%25C3%25A8ces%2Bfournies%2Bdoivent%2B%25C3%25AAtre%2Boriginales%2Bou%2Bcopies%2Bcertifi%25C3%25A9es%2Bconformes%2B%25C3%25A0%2Bl%25E2%2580%2599original%2Bde%2Bmoins%2Bde%2Btrois%2Bmois.
```

i got this exception :

```
nov. 10, 2016 10:10:29 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFOS: Error parsing HTTP request header
```

it's a bad request

```
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 bad request
```

Or it's a long query because the link it work directly when i save the form and the user is logged

So How can I solve this to prevent my admins repeating a long form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a request URL of over 4000 characters (and your example is above 5000) you can get an Http 400 response, depending on browser/server side implementation.

Comment: Yes thanks man you're right we solve it by increasing the http header max size following this answer http://serverfault.com/questions/56691/whats-the-maximum-url-length-in-tomcat

Answer (score 0):

> I have a long form to fit and sometimes the session is invalid and
>   when I press the submit button I lose all of my data. Luckily, I
>   managed to save the next url after the redirect on login form.

You can't use url redirect in your case as the form the entire data will be visible in the URL.

You can resolve this by saving the user data into database and then dispatching to the next (2nd) page because you are saying that the user session might get timeout. So, if you save it to database, then you can actually prompt the user from where he has left.

Comment: thanks for the answer but it's not a confidential data so it's not a big deal if it is visible in the URL and to save data I also need the info about the user.